# String to Double and leading whitespace

Tags: swift, string, standard-library

I found odd behavior in the Swift standard library struct Double(). This function converts a string representing a number into a double precision number. All well and good.

I recently discovered odd behavior wrt to leading whitespace, namely the conversion fails if a single blank character space leads a valid number string:

Example (Xcode Debugger)

```
(lldb) po Double("11.8000")
▿ Optional<Double>
  - some : 11.8

(lldb) po Double(" 11.8000")
nil
```

I have not seen this documented, so I post it here.
The inelegant fix is:

```
let myNumber = Double(myString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))
```

Any better solution? I mean aside from a simple String Extension to replace trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) with trim().   I would think Double() and its relatives should be able to internally handle leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fully documented. Look at the documentation for the [`init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2926277-init) method that takes a `StringProtocol`.

Near the end of all of the examples, it states:

> Passing any other format or any additional characters as `text` results in `nil`. For example, the following conversions result in `nil`:
>
> ```
> Double(" 5.0")      // Includes whitespace
> ```

So your solution to trim whitespace before conversion is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, I looked at the standard library entry for Double, and googled around the web as well.  I failed to look at the init method. My bad.

Comment: Not to belabor the point about trimmed strings, it does seem reasonable to me (at least), that trimming could be internal. External blanks are a far cry from random punctuation and alpha characters in the midst of numeric chars. Just looks hacky. But again, thanks for the response.